# Drawing tools to add circles, arrows, lines for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, map-drawing

I'm pretty new in QGIS and i'm searching a drawing tool like it is possible to find in microsoft word or excel.  I search something very user friendly (for dummies!) to add circles, arrows, lines... with no need to create a new layer!!

Can you help me?

Comment: QGIS is designed to edit layers - https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html if you want a graphical application like inkscape.

Comment: in QGIS Layout view you can add arrows http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html

Comment: But it doesn't exits an application or a toolbar like inkscape directly into QGIS?  It's not necessary to be big like inscape! Thanks!

Comment: Besides, everything you create will be in a layer. That is the basic data storage type (i.e. the shapefile), without it you can't create or save anything (cause it wont know where to store your information).

Comment: @eric this is interesting - could you comment on what you're trying to do? I've done stuff like this in ArcMap, but always ended up working with real features rather than graphics (ArcMap has a graphics toolbar that can draw in layout or data view...)

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve? Are you looking to geographical data? or do you just want to draw?

Comment: If you want perfect circles create points and buffer around them

Comment: This seems like a neat feature, you should consider adding a feature request at [QGIS Features](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues?set_filter=1&tracker_id=2)

Answer (score 7):

**NOTE** the plugin referenced below is no longer maintained.  The QGIS plugin site suggests using the **[CAD Digitize](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/CADDigitize/)** plugin instead (as of January 2018).

There's the **[Rectangles Ovals Digitizing](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/rectovalDigit/)** plugin that does just that and the shapes you create are saved in a layer (start editing that layer first).

[image: Rectangles Ovals Plugin screenshot]

It allows you to draw Rectangles, Squares, Ovals and Circles.

But I'm not sure about a plugin for arrows and other diagram type object.
Those can be added in the Print Composer Layout, there is a separate toolbar for that.

[image: print composer toolbar for shapes]

Comment: CADDigitize is not supported by QGis 3+

Answer (score 1):

In the plugins menu, search for Qdraw (in the not installed tab, or in the installed tab if you might already have it...). Will save to a memory layer, need to name the shapes you draw.

Comment: For QGIS3, I've found QDraw to be a good reliable alternative to the old Rectangle, Circles plugin from QGIS 2.x. The added functionality of it creating the shapes on a virtual layer is really useful if you need to temporarily cut an area.

Answer (score 0):

As for the arrows, you would probably need to create a shapefile layer in which you draw a line for the arrows you want.

You can either do this: [Link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94064/how-to-indicate-flow-of-a-watershed-feature)

or you can just style the line as you wish and combine it with a 'symbol' line over it. You can set '>' as arrow ends, and select to only display one symbol at the end of the line.

Example: [Circulation plan with simple arrows](https://www.digi-cms.be/meulebeke.be/website/1863-www/version/default/part/AttachmentData/data/Gewijzigd%20stratenplan.jpg)

First option is more for a a series of arrows, individual ones you could style using the second option.

Answer (score -1):

Draw grid in QGIS over a map using OSM overpass server, see my repository
on github : https://github.com/waelhammoudeh/mk-grid
It is not point and click, but I hope somebody will find it useful.