# Can I draw GRAPHICS (not vector) like in ArcMap and convert it to shape?

Tags: qgis

In ArcMap one can **draw graphics** (lines, rectangles, circles, etc) that are NOT vectors but can be then converted to shape files. Is same possible in QGIS?

I have only found to make directly vectors in edit mode.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Estiivan! Don't think this is (currently) possible to do in QGIS. You can draw the shapes you mentioned as described in this post but these are treated as vectors: [Drawing tools to add circles, arrows, lines for QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94728/drawing-tools-to-add-circles-arrows-lines-for-qgis).

Comment: I think what you want is not available in the QGIS map view.  See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94728/drawing-tools-to-add-circles-arrows-lines-for-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1.  You can add shapes to the composer layout.  Note, ArcGIS Pro has dropped ArcMap style graphics in favor of adding vectors to a default file geodatabase for each project. You could create a shapefile whose only task is to hold "graphics" from one or many projects and then copy those into any layer you like.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your question with what QGIS version.

In 2.16 you already can add circular string out of the box.
[image]
The CadDigitize plugin is what you're looking for.
[image]