# Assigning Arrow Symbology on Point-to-Point Connections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, symbology, excel

I have an excel file containing points of departure and arrival places and their lat/long.

I have lat/long for both arrival and departure cities in spreadsheet.
I have created seperate point feature shapefile for departure cities and origin cities.
want to assign symbology for these files displaying arrows going from origin to destination. (if displaying arrows is possible without symbology, would be accepted).
I want to create a shapefile of this excel displaying arrows going from the point of origin to the point of destination.

The lines should be curved but i have no information abut the angles or bearings

please suggest a procedure.

I'm a newbie at this!

Comment: You have tags for both QGIS and ArcGIS (presumably for Desktop).  Which are you using?  And what have you researched/tried before posting?

Comment: i'm using ARCGIS desktop rite now. i tried assigning symbology through layer properties but it only assigns arrow symbols to the points instead of drawing an arrow line from origin to destination

Comment: Please use the **edit** button beneath your question to revise it with clarifications such as this.  Are you saying now that your question is about symbolizing lines and not about creating the lines from the spreadsheet?  And have you tried the solution to a similar question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10206/directional-flow-arrows-for-sewer-lines

Comment: From your question title you want to assign arrow to points. in you question body you want to assign arrow to lines. What type of curve do you want to create? do you have any information about the curve or just the start and end points? Please share more details in your question.

Comment: have edited my question..please have a look and suggest

Answer (score 1):

A line with arrows can be made with the line symbology, depending on the software you want to use: [How to indicate flow of a watershed feature?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94064/how-to-indicate-flow-of-a-watershed-feature) . A simple `>` text symbology can work too.

For the curved lines, you have to create great circle lines on a custom aeqd projection. See [great circles in QGIS and export in 3857 webmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133026/great-circles-in-qgis-and-export-in-3857-webmap) for a workflow.